# Pandas Plotly assign colors by label

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I'm plotting 7 different DataFrames and I'm trying to assign them color according to my labels but when I do it I get the error

> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of
> argument `color` is 7, whereas the length of  previously-processed
> arguments ['x', 'wide_variable_0', 'wide_variable_1',
> 'wide_variable_2', 'wide_variable_3', 'wide_variable_4',
> 'wide_variable_5', 'wide_variable_6'] is 73

I'm lost because why would he try to label according to the x axis? That's the only one with 73 values. Also I don't know where do those wide_variables come from.

This is the code I'm using, it works fine unless I try to assign colors:

```
fig = px.line(df, 
        y = [ejey.sin_vac_uci, ejey2.una_dosis_uci, ejey3.dos_dosis_uci, ejey4.dos_dosis_comp_uci, ejey5.dosis_unica_uci, ejey6.dosis_unica_comp_uci,
         ejey7.dosis_ref_comp_uci],
        x = df.semana_epidemiologica, 
         title='Incidencia en UCI',
         color=df.columns[8:], 
         )
    fig.show()
```

When I print(df.columns[8:]) I see exactly what I want: An array of 7 different labels but for some reason python is expecting 73..

Comment: Without more specific data, I'm not sure if my comment is correct, but it seems to me that you are giving column data on the y-axis with wide format data. That is correct, but I think it is due to the fact that you are giving column data for color. I think you need to retreat to a long format data frame and add a column for the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `color` is used to identify colors for each data point. More information [here](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/). As you have each of your line data in separate columns, you can use `color_discrete_sequence` to set colors of each line. As you have not provided any data, am using random data to show an example. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rand1': random.sample(range(1, 50), 20),
                    'rand2': random.sample(range(1, 30), 20),
                    'rand3': random.sample(range(1, 30), 20),
                    'rand4': random.sample(range(1, 30), 20),
                    'rand5': random.sample(range(1, 30), 20),
                    'myX' : range(20)})
fig = px.line(df, 
        y = ['rand1', 'rand2', 'rand3', 'rand4', 'rand5'],
              x= 'myX', color_discrete_sequence=["yellow", "blue", "pink", "skyblue", "red"])
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Super Graph')
fig.show()
```

**Output Graph**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. What I've been unable to do is to modify the legend. I'm getting just 'wide_variable_0'. I found how to modify names when each line is a trace but that is not my case